# How to sending data to a specific activity that is already started?

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose we have two simple applications, so we have two different packages.
Each of these packages has an `Activity` that can be launched by clicking the application icon. Suppose that the two activities are as follows:

- `MyFirstActivity`, which is into the package `org.firstexample.firstactivity`
- `MySecondActivity`, which is into the package `org.secondexample.secondactivity`

Suppose we have launched the `MyFirstActivity` activity, so it is running.
Could the `MySecondActivity` activity send data directly to the `MyFirstActivity` activity?

I would like the two activities (which are in different packages) can communicate with each other by exchanging data.

Answer (score 1):

if you are launching MySecondActivity  from MyFirstActivity then use this way:

in Activity MyFirstActivity:

```
Intent intent25 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setClassName("org.secondexample",
"org.secondexample.MySecondActivity").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("rg.secondexample",
"org.secondexample.MySecondActivity"));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Name", "test");
intent25.putExtras(bundle);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent25);
```

and in MySecondActivity oncreate()

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String name = bundle.getString("Name");
```

Comment: Ok, but if `MySecondActivity` is currently running?

Comment: as you know in android only one activity is visble to user means running at a time. if activity is not running then it may be in onPouse state or finished.

Comment: You are right! And if there was a service instead of `MyFirstActivity`? In other words, given an activity (which is running) and a service: how to make them communicate with each other (without resuming or destroying the activity)?

Comment: if you have a service and a activity then use custom broadcast for communicate between service and activity

Comment: Should the service send a broadcast intent? Is not available a unicast communication?

Comment: yes if you want to send data from service to activity then service broadcast intent or if u want to send data from activity to service then activity broadcast intent.note in this process u may required two broadcast receiver to register

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10613/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-enzom83)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data without resuming on destroying activity then you have to make listener for that..

```
public class MyFirstActivity extends Activity implements OnDataChanged {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

@Override
public void onChange(int a) {
    Log.e("", "a : " + a);

}

}
```

MySecondActivity.java

```
public class MySecondActivity extends Activity {

private OnDataChanged mOnDataChanged;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sendData(10);
}

public interface OnDataChanged {
    public void onChange(int a);
}

private void sendData(int a) {
    mOnDataChanged.onChange(a);
}

}
```

MySecondActivity is sending 10 to MyFirstActivity by implementing listener of MySecondActivity...